# loading in json file giving errors in python

Tags: python, json

I'm loading in the following json that is contained in a text file:

```
{
"data sources" : [
"http://www.gcmap.com/" 
] ,
"metros" : [
{
"code" : "SCL" ,
"name" : "Santiago" ,
"country" : "CL" ,
"continent" : "South America" ,
"timezone" : -4 ,
"coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
"population" : 6000000 ,
"region" : 1
} , {
"code" : "LIM" ,
"name" : "Lima" ,
"country" : "PE" ,
"continent" : "South America" ,
"timezone" : -5 ,
"coordinates" : {"S" : 12, "W" : 77} ,
"population" : 9050000 ,
"region" : 1
} ]}
```

And then I put this file in the same directory as the python file that will open it and use the following code:

```
import json

json_file = open('json.txt')
data = json.load(json_file)
json_file.close()

print (data)
```

However this gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tylerharrington/Desktop/workspace/Assignment2/src/cs242assignment2/UserInterface.py", line 11, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 264, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/json/__init__.py", line 309, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 352, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/json/decoder.py", line 368, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Does this indicate an error with the python file or and error in my code?

Comment: The code is perfectly working with the data file above

Comment: I created a text file called json.txt and then copied/pasted your code into my interpreter and it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Your file probably has some invalid character at the first line just after the opening brace `{`

Dump the file with `od` to check the file content or in windows examine the file with a hex editor

Or simply run the following code snippet with your file content

```
with open('json.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print [hex(ord(e)) for e in line]
```

This will give you a fair idea about the offending character

or simply just

```
hex(ord(open('test.txt').read(2)[1]))
```

Comment: What should one do after they find the 'offending character'?